# Android Studio Emulator: not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

So Im getting this error when I try to run my an emulator through Android Virtual device manager.

```
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 1024 MB
```

Can someone tell me how to adjust the AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to make this work?  Or what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!!!! 
you need to reinstall the HAXM by running a file. goto sdk stored directory andfollow the steps:

> tools>extras>intel>haxm and run the executables silent.bat and install.exe.
>   but make the memory allocated to greater than 1536MB i.e 1.9 GB.

The other way can be :

> 1. Goto Android virtual device manager and add a new device
> 2. Setup a new device with memory lesser than 1024 MB. But you can still use your preferred android version but you need to compromise with the device. choose device with minimum screen resolution.

Comment: Thank you.  The second and simpler option of reducing the memory size of  the new device worked for me.   I added the new device and reduced the memory through AVD manager and by clicking on advance settings. Thank you for your help.